# TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include()

Tags: django, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am new to django and python. During url mapping to views i am getting following error: 
TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().

Urls. py code:-

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^posts/$', "posts.views.post_home"), #posts is module and post_home 
]                                              # is a function in view.
```

views.py code:-

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
# Create your views here.
#function based views

def post_home(request):
    response = "<h1>Success</h1>"
    return HttpResponse(response)
```

**Traceback**

[image]

Comment: Instead of posting an image of text, post the actual text.

Comment: Replace your admin url pattern with this one `url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls))`. Also import - include `from django.conf.urls import include`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In 1.10, you can no longer pass import paths to `url()`, you need to pass the actual view function:

```
from posts.views import post_home

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^posts/$', post_home),
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response and it is perfect way to do that. But what we have to do when we have more functions from the same view? any suggestion on the same ?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. More functions from the same view module? If so, just import them all: `from posts.views import post_home, other_view`.

Comment: What if one is using class based views?

Comment: @RishabhAgrahari Then you need to import the view class and use `View.as_view()` as the view function.

Answer (score 2):

Replace your admin url pattern with this

```
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls))
```

So your urls.py becomes :

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^posts/$', "posts.views.post_home"), #posts is module and post_home 
]
```

admin urls are callable by include (before 1.9).

Comment: `admin.site.urls` is the only case where you actually should not use `include()`. Doing so will result in a deprecation warning, because the changes to `include()` in 1.9 are incompatible with how `admin.site.urls` works. Also check out [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#hooking-adminsite-instances-into-your-urlconf) on this.

Comment: Exactly....I read in doc the same. We should not use include() for admin. But i tried the solution given by kapil.

Comment: @knbk , you are right, but its not incompatible and also will not raise any deprecation warning(for now atleast) and yes its just not necessary now. Thanks.

Comment: In 1.9 it will raise a `PendingDeprecationWarning`, which is silent by default. In 1.10 it will raise a `DeprecationWarning`.

Answer (score 1):

For Django 1.11.2
In the main urls.py write :

```
from django.conf.urls import include,url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^posts/', include("Post.urls")),
]
```

And in the appname/urls.py file write:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.post_home),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer is in **project-dir/urls.py**

```
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.conf.urls import url, include
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to complement the answer from @knbk, we could use the template below:

**as is in 1.9:**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls), #it's not allowed to use the include() in the admin.urls
    url(r'^posts/$', include(posts.views.post_home), 
]
```

**as should be in 1.10:**

```
from your_project_django.your_app_django.view import name_of_your_view

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^name_of_the_view/$', name_of_the_view),
]
```

Remember to create in your_app_django >> views.py the function to render your view.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass actual view function

from posts.views import post_home

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^posts/$', post_home),
]

This works fine!
You can have a read at [URL Dispatcher Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/)
and here [Common Reguler Expressions Django URLs](https://github.com/codingforentrepreneurs/Guides/blob/master/all/common_url_regex.md)