# django error on simple app while run the program

Tags: python, django

Control is coming to this line and the raising the TypeError:

raise TypeError('view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().')

```
TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().
```

Any help on how to resolve this will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: please post the code and format the error

Comment: What's in your `urls.py`?

Comment: You are probably following an old django tutorial, but using latest django, therefore setting up the urls.py using deprecate methods. I think this is the most likely case.

Comment: @dr ali, please check my answer and try it.

Comment: check this answer:- [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38394598/typeerror-view-must-be-a-callable-or-a-list-tuple-in-the-case-of-include](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38394598/typeerror-view-must-be-a-callable-or-a-list-tuple-in-the-case-of-include)

Answer (score 1):

String reference is not allowed since Django 1.10.

```
import django.contrib.auth.views

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^login/$', django.contrib.auth.views.login, name='login'),
    ...
```

Change your urls.py code as mention above and it might work.